# Get value from java application class in kotlin service

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i have a java application class and i want to get a value from it in kotlin service .

i try to do it with this code but it's return null

```
myValue = (application as App).getNumValue
```

some of my code

Application Class:

```
private String numValue = "";


public String getNumValue() {
    return numValue;
}

public void setNumValue(String numValue) {
    this.numValue = numValue;
}
```

java Activity for set value :

```
 ((App) this.getApplication()).setNumValue(enNum);
```

Kotlin Service And Read Value :

```
myValue = (application as App).getNumValue()

Toast.makeText(this, myValue +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: You could just `val value = (application as App).numValue ` for getting the value and `(application as App).numValue = otherValue` to set it. Kotlin by default changes this to call getters and setters in compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I was solved my problem with :

```
val myValue = (this.application as App).getNumValue()

Toast.makeText(this, myValue +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```